# JPanel doesn't draw image until mouse click

Tags: java, image, jframe, jpanel, bufferedimage

I have a small, simple program I've started and have a strange bug I haven't been able to figure out or find the cause for online.

All my program does right now is build a JFrame, build a JPanel, and draw an image onto the JPanel from a thread. The issue is, the image does not display unless I click in the Frame, left click, right click, or even click with my mouse wheel makes the image display, but resizing the frame doesn't make the image display. I've tried validate() on the panel and frames both, and I've tried putting repaint() in the code called by the thread but the image flickers when repaint() is in the code.

I put a print statement in the code that actually draws the image, but the statement never shows up until I click in the frame. I've walked through with the debugger and the code seems to be getting called correctly though. If I put a print statement anywhere in code being called from the main thread's update() function, the image displays correctly without having to click.

Here is my code, any suggestions would be appreciated:

The Frame

```
public class GameFrame extends JFrame{

  int w = 1300;
  int h = 740;

  public GameFrame() {

    this.setSize(w, h);
    setTitle("Frame");

    GamePanel panel = new GamePanel(w, h);
    this.add(panel);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    GameFrame gameFrame = new GameFrame();
  }
}
```

The Panel

```
public class GamePanel extends JPanel implements Runnable{

//core classes
GameRenderer renderer;
GameManager manager;
GameLoader loader;

//graphics stuff
private Graphics dbg;
private Image dbImage = null;
private int panelWidth;
private int panelHeight;

//game updating stuff
Thread animator;
boolean running;

public GamePanel(int w, int h) {
    this.setSize(w, h);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setFocusable(true);
    this.panelWidth = w;
    this.panelHeight = h;

    renderer = new GameRenderer();
    manager = new GameManager();
    loader = new GameLoader();

    startGame();
}

private void startGame() {
    animator = new Thread(this, "Animator");
    animator.start();
    running = true;
}

public void run() {
    while(running) {
        gameAction();
    }
}

//everything that needs to be updated continuously
private void gameAction() {
    //updateGame(); // Need code here to update everything
    gameRender(); // Draw to the double buffer.
    paintScreen(); // Draw double buffer to screen.
}

/**
 * Draws the game image to the buffer.
 * 
 */
private void gameRender() {
    if(dbImage == null) {
        dbImage = createImage(this.panelWidth, this.panelHeight);
        return;
    }
    dbg = dbImage.getGraphics();
    renderer.draw((Graphics2D) dbg, panelWidth, panelHeight);
}

/**
 * Draws the game image to the screen by drawing the buffer.
 */
private void paintScreen() {
    Graphics g;
    try {
        g = this.getGraphics();
        if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null))  {
            g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, null);
            g.dispose();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println("Graphics context error: " + e); }
}

}
```

Image Renderer

```
public class GameRenderer {

ImageManipulator im = new ImageManipulator();

/**
 * Actually draw everything that needs to be drawn
 * Layering also happens here 
 */
public void draw(Graphics2D g,int screenWidth, int screenHeight) {
    BufferedImage tileImg = im.loadImage("Images/tile.png");
    Tile tile = new Tile(tileImg, 30, 30);
    tile.draw(g);
}

}
```

Class with image I'm trying to draw

```
public class Tile {

BufferedImage tileImg;
//x and y values based on tile grid - z based on height up
int tileX;
int tileY;
int tileZ;
//actual coordinate of top left corner of tile *image*
int pixelX;
int pixelY;

public Tile(BufferedImage img, int pixelX, int pixelY) {
    this.pixelX = pixelX;
    this.pixelY = pixelY;
    this.tileImg = img;
}

public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(tileImg, pixelX, pixelY, null);
}

}
```

Again, any suggestions or ideas would help. I'm out of ideas of what might be causing this.
Also, does anybody know why this might be working with a print statement included but not without one?

Comment: I'm not an expert on how graphics are managed in swing under the hood, but I used to call `repaint()`. (A quick-fix for your problem would be to add: `update(g)` to the paintScreen method).

Comment: That helped narrow it down a little. I'm getting the same results if I put update(g) within this if statement: `if ((g != null) && (dbImage != null))`. If I put it immediately after this line `g = this.getGraphics();` I get a few null pointer exceptions (which makes sense) but it displays correctly. I guess something with that if statement is causing it to not render.

Comment: No, using that `getGraphics()` method does not put the graphics on the screen when you are done, AFAIK. `repaint()` is the preferred method to do this.

Comment: Also, a very good resource for a game loop in Java is Bonsai Game Library: https://github.com/BonsaiDen/Bonsai-Game-Library/blob/master/src/org/bonsai/dev/Game.java

Comment: getGraphics is NOT how painting in Swing is done, you should be painting within the defined paint chain (overriding paintComponent for components) which will tell you when painting should be done. If you want to control when painting is done, you should use a BufferedStrategy instead. The problem is, Anything you paint using getGraphics could be (and probably is been) painted over when the RepaintManager decides an update is required

Comment: @MartijnCourteaux repaint is a good idea, but the op is painting outside the prescribed paint chain for Swing, also, it's not recommended to call or override update within Swing (nor should you ever call paint directly, unless you have created your own Graphics context for screen grabbing or printing)

Comment: Also, you should NEVER dispose of a Graphics context that you didn't create yourself

Comment: @MadProgrammer: I know. I forgot to add the word "dirty" to "quick fix" ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have misunderstood how to do custom painting in a Swing component.  It is not correct to call `this.getGraphics()`.  The correct way to paint a Swing component is to override its `paintComponent` method.  Note that the first line in that method **must** call `super.paintComponent`:

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    if (dbImage != null) {
        g.drawImage(dbImage, 0, 0, this);
    }
}
```

Also note that you must not attempt to dispose the Graphics object, since you didn't create it and it is under Swing's control, not yours.

For full details, see the [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) tutorial.

When you want your game to repaint, simply call the panel's [repaint](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#repaint--) method.  Thus, your `gameAction` method should replace paintScreen() with repaint(), which will automatically call your panel's paintComponent method (and some other methods;  as that tutorial explains, painting isn't a simple thing).

You will need to put a short [sleep](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep-long-) call inside the loop in your `run()` method.  If you try to update and repaint the game constantly, the program won't have time to actually draw anything.  For instance, if you want the game to update five times per second (that is, every 200 milliseconds):

```
try {
    while (running) {
        gameAction();
        Thread.sleep(200);
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have two guesses. The first one is the startGame method in GamePanel. Put the line "running = true;" before you call "start()" on your thread.

If that doesn't work, try this in your run() method in GamePanel:

```
public void run() { gameAction(); }
```

If it renders, then the problem is the while loop.

Comment: hmm it doesn't look like it was either of those. I even tried `if(true) gameAction();` within the run function to verify.